# Long tail amplifier using current mirrors

Tags: bjt, current-mirror, voltage-controlled-amplifier

[image]

I have built this in the [Multisim simulator](https://www.multisim.com) and it works there as desired.  Now I have built it on a "lame" breadboard.

Is the upper PNP current mirror  correct?

Since the "left" leg behaves opposed to the "right" leg when in working order, the current should follow the left leg, right?

Using Ohm's law: 5V / 100 Ohm = 0.05 ampere, which would impossible to achieve from a 78L05.  The probe shows 670 microamperes, albeit having 2.5 volt (via a voltage divider of 100K ) on the base of both NPN transistors. Can the output of the simulator be trusted?

It seems the voltage drop is huge from the upper 5 volt rail to beneath the pair of NPN transistors.

The second current mirror I took from the LM13700 datasheet:

[image]

It needed different values over the opamp to achieve the same output as above.  It is hugely offset towards the positive power rail, hitting it and chopping a little piece of the the wave.  Although the voltages on the tail are similar to upper schematic the difference between the legs is bigger than the schematic above.

I just want to omit the balance trimmer between the legs.

[image]

to prevent clicking sounds from "Gates" on Q6 (Q4)  and Q3 (Q3) from the upper schematic, I have added a Zener Diode to generate 2.5V + a Trimmer to aim for the 0.6 V bias voltage for the bases of the transistors.
Question is now, What type of capacitor would be suited best.
Polarized or non Polarized and what value?

Comment: *the current should follow the left leg, right?*  Right ! as in correct... 100 Ohm ?? where

Comment: * 0.05 ampere, which would impossible to achieve from a 78L05.*  Why not . It's rated for 0.1A !

Comment: I wouldn't trust those results as I expect just over  9.4V across RE8 and Ic just under 1mA

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 R3 and R4 in the upper Schematic are 100 Ohm, i guess, ... I'm gonna stick to that current mirror. it seam to be the right choice ... but that's part of the question.
i just wanna prevent a trimmer between R3 and R4 and have it auto balanced.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 ( I wouldn't trust those results as I expect just over 9.4V across RE8 and Ic just under 1mA ) ...., i'm working on that right now, will update the question in a few with an additional image, thank you for your reply.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 updated the "question" with image.

Comment: 1. You have no design specs 2. you have undefined component tolerances  3. Therefore you have undefined solutions unless you use a trimpot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129119/discussion-between-naturaldemon-and-tony-stewart-ee75).